# cannot find symbol:method getFactory()

Tags: java, jar, jackson

> symbol:   method getFactory()
> location: variable mapper of type org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper

I already added below jar

[image]

Below is how I import them

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*,java.text.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.swing.*" %>
<%@page import="java.text.DateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@ page language="java"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@ include file="dbconfig.jsp" %>


<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"%>
<%@page import="java.net.*"%>
<%@page import="org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties"
        
        
        
import=" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding"
import=" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory"
import=" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException"
import=" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator"
import=" org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException"   
        
        
%>
```

and below is my code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.getFactory().configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII, true);        
String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString( jsonMap );
response.getOutputStream().print( jsonStr );
```

I get error in `getFactory()` and `ESCAPE_NON_ASCII`

How to get rid of error in `getFactory()` and `ESCAPE_NON_ASCII`

Comment: add to build path | add to classpath?

Comment: add to build path?how can i add to build path? i think i havent done that

Comment: right click, check the list (there must be something similar)

Comment: in eclipse with rightclick on Project - properties - Java build path

Comment: @mayha i am using netbeans i will try it anyway

Comment: check the build path. then check the getFactory() method is actually available in the jar file or not. if you can put the source code part, it might be easy to help

Comment: Looking at `ObjectMapper` in Jackson 1.8.x and 1.9.x _there is no_ method `getFactory()`, hence that symbol (the method) cannot be found.

Comment: @Thomas which one does have that method you can share with us

Comment: @mayha i checked already all the jar are there in Compile tab in netbeans

Comment: @Thomas i now have one problem i get error in `ESCAPE_NON_ASCII` when i remove `import=" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding"
import=" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory"
import=" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException"
import=" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator"
import=" org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException" ` error is gone but i get error in `JsonGenerator` which other import i need?

Answer (score 0):

Your imports look like you are using Jackson 1.9.x which doesn't have a method `getFactory()` in `ObjectMapper`. There is a method `getJsonFactory()`, but you'd probably not need it. Just call `mapper.configure( JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII, true );`

Comment: i now have one problem i get error in `ESCAPE_NON_ASCII` when i remove `import=" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding" import=" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory" import=" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException" import=" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator" import=" org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException"` error is gone but i get error in `JsonGenerator` which other import i need?

Comment: @BrownmanRevival that depends on the error which should already contain the information you need. If I'd have to guess I'd say you need to import `JsonGenerator.Feature` (with the correct package of course).

Comment: i tried removing all i am left with `import=" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator"` when i have this `JsonGenerator` does not return error but `ESCAPE_NON_ASCII` gives error i will try to imnport what you said

Comment: error says `cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ESCAPE_NON_ASCII
  location: class Feature` i tried importing like `import="org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator.Feature"` didnt remove the error

Comment: Hmm as per documentation `ESCAPE_NON_ASCII` is present since Jackson 1.8 is and located in jackson-mapper-asl. Looking at your library it seems as if you're using 3 different versions which might be incompatible to one another (at least between 1.x and 2.x): jackson-mapper-asl 1.8.4, jackson-all 1.9.0 and jackson-core 2.0.5. Please check that and if possible try to use matching versions.

Comment: sorry for this but i need help i remove other and i am left with `jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.4` , `jaskcon-core-2.0.5` and `com.springsource.org.codehouse.jackson-1.4.2` but the `JsonGenerator` is not in them i dont have idea which jar contains that package